# how can I substitute a matched string in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I have a string ="/One/Two/Three/Four"

I want to convert it to ="Four"

I can do this in one line in perl

```
string =~ s/.*+\///g
```

How Can  I do this in python?

Comment: What is the constant? Do you want to take the last word after the last "/"?

Comment: Your `perl` replacement example would result in an empty string; not the string `"Four"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `re` module can handle regular expressions. For this case, you'd do

```
import re

my_str = "/One/Two/Three/Four"
new_str = re.sub(".*/", "", my_str)
# 'Four'
```

`re.sub()` is the regex replacement method. Like your perl regex, we simply look for any number of characters, followed by a slash, and then replace that with the empty string. What's left is what's after the last slash, which is 4.

Comment: Thanks This is xactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

```
str_name="/One/Two/Three/Four"
str_name.split('/')[-1]
```

In general, split is a safe way to convert a string into a list based on some reg-ex. Then, we can call the last element in that list, which happens to be "Four" in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `str.split()` doesn't support complex regex. To split on a regex, you need to use `re.split()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The are alot of possibilities to solve this. One way would be by indexing the string. Other string method can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp)

```
string ="/One/Two/Three/Four"
string[string.index('Four'):]
```

Additionally you could split the string by the slash with `.split('/')`

```
print(string.split('/')[-1])
```

Another option would be regular expressions: see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)